# Is there a way to import and run a function from another script in python that will import libraries for the current script

Tags: python, function, shared-libraries

For example I am trying to import this function "load_modules() which is in a script called "setup.py" into another script using the code directly below.

```
   def load_modules():
        import cv2
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd
        from scipy import ndimage
        import os
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        import matplotlib.image as mpimg
        import time
        import math
        import random
        from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import map_coordinates
        from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

    from setup import *
    load_modules()
    img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 1)
```

The first two lines run fine so the files functions have been imported and there appears to be no issue running the load_modules() function however I get an error on the last line saying that cv2 is not defined.

Comment: You import the modules inside a function, so the names that refer to them (`cv2`, ...) are local to the function. Just import them normally, that is at the top level, at the start of your `setup` script.

Comment: I actually set them as global variables and that worked too, thanks for your help